# Скрипт для автосоздания блоков

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть сервак на который пишется видеопоток с камер наблюдения.Я делаю сайт для пользователей которые будут отсматривать эти камеры.

потоковою передачу настроил.

на сервер так же пишется тайм лайн с камер. это 15 минутные видео за весь день
мне нужно чтоб каждый тайм лайн выводился в качестве блока с сылкой на это видео.
видео будут создаваться в папе и при каждом создании скрипт должен создавать блок на сайте со ссылкой на это видео

Comment: А где собственно вопрос? Что у вас конкретно не получается или что вызывает затруднение, чем вам может помочь сообщество?

Comment: Нужна помощь в создании скрипта, который будет при появлении в папке фидеофайла формата mp4 на странице создавать такой блок, с сылкой на новый файл

Comment: <li data-title="Демо Ролик 2" data-type="m4v"
            data-url="http://95.78.250.41/TFzBcetLvqzBqeYccxxPLzLH149RTr/videos/signum/Gdvu1tX6Eq/2019-10-23T17-30-01.mp4"></li>

Comment: В таком случае при переходе на страницу или клике по ссылке выполняется php скрипт который сканирует директорию и выводит ссылки на файлы в html, в чем проблема? Если нет события можно добавить задачу в крон который запускает скрипт, можно также хранить файлы с данными в базе и от туда вытаскивать их по запросу а запись в базу оставить за кроном и отдельным скриптом

Comment: а есть готовое решение этого скрипта?